# Parsing Lines of Log File for Specific Entries

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following line in a log file (with lots and lots of lines, and not all the same kind of log entry)

```
5/9/2013 3:01:38 PM|Xml Sent to Engine <catalog><book id=\"bk101\"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price><publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date><description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description></book><book id=\"bk102\"><author>Ralls, Kim</author><title>Midnight Rain</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date><description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description></book><book id=\"bk103\"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>Maeve Ascendant</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date><description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology society in England, the young survivors lay the foundation for a new society.</description></book><book id=\"bk104\"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>Oberon's Legacy</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date><description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve Ascendant.</description></book><book id=\"bk105\"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>The Sundered Grail</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date><description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, battle one another for control of England. Sequel to Oberon's Legacy.</description></book><book id=\"bk106\"><author>Randall, Cynthia</author><title>Lover Birds</title><genre>Romance</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date><description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description></book><book id=\"bk107\"><author>Thurman, Paula</author><title>Splish Splash</title><genre>Romance</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date><description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description></book><book id=\"bk108\"><author>Knorr, Stefan</author><title>Creepy Crawlies</title><genre>Horror</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date><description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description></book><book id=\"bk109\"><author>Kress, Peter</author><title>Paradox Lost</title><genre>Science Fiction</genre><price>6.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date><description>After an inadvertant trip through a HeisenbergUncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems of being quantum.</description></book><book id=\"bk110\"><author>O'Brien, Tim</author><title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>36.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date><description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description></book><book id=\"bk111\"><author>O'Brien, Tim</author><title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>36.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date><description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, SAX and more.</description></book><book id=\"bk112\"><author>Galos, Mike</author><title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>49.95</price><publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date><description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are integrated into a comprehensive development environment.</description></book></catalog>
```

What I'm able to rely on is the "tag" 
"Xml Sent to Engine "

I"m trying to get the correct C#/RegEx to

```
1.  Identity the correct line via the tag.
and
2.  Get the xml at the end of the line.
```

I've tried this, but cannot figure out the syntax for the regex.

```
string line = string.Empty;

line = "5/9/2013 3:01:38 PM|Xml Sent to Engine <catalog><book id=\"bk101\"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price><publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date><description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description></book><book id=\"bk102\"><author>Ralls, Kim</author><title>Midnight Rain</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date><description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description></book><book id=\"bk103\"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>Maeve Ascendant</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date><description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology society in England, the young survivors lay the foundation for a new society.</description></book><book id=\"bk104\"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>Oberon's Legacy</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date><description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve Ascendant.</description></book><book id=\"bk105\"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>The Sundered Grail</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date><description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, battle one another for control of England. Sequel to Oberon's Legacy.</description></book><book id=\"bk106\"><author>Randall, Cynthia</author><title>Lover Birds</title><genre>Romance</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date><description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description></book><book id=\"bk107\"><author>Thurman, Paula</author><title>Splish Splash</title><genre>Romance</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date><description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description></book><book id=\"bk108\"><author>Knorr, Stefan</author><title>Creepy Crawlies</title><genre>Horror</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date><description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description></book><book id=\"bk109\"><author>Kress, Peter</author><title>Paradox Lost</title><genre>Science Fiction</genre><price>6.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date><description>After an inadvertant trip through a HeisenbergUncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems of being quantum.</description></book><book id=\"bk110\"><author>O'Brien, Tim</author><title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>36.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date><description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description></book><book id=\"bk111\"><author>O'Brien, Tim</author><title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>36.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date><description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, SAX and more.</description></book><book id=\"bk112\"><author>Galos, Mike</author><title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>49.95</price><publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date><description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are integrated into a comprehensive development environment.</description></book></catalog>";


            string regExPattern = @"";
            regExPattern = @"(?<tag>\bXml Sent to Engine\b)(?<sep1>\b \b)(?<xmlFragment>^<catalog>.*)";

            //try to macth the line using regular expressions
            Match parsed = Regex.Match(line, regExPattern);
            if (parsed.Success || true==true)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < parsed.Groups.Count; i++)
                {
                    string abc = parsed.Groups[i].Value;
                    System.Console.WriteLine(abc);

                }

                string xmlFragment = string.Empty;
                if (null != parsed.Groups["xmlFragment"])
                {
                    xmlFragment = parsed.Groups["xmlFragment"].Value;
                }



            }
```

EDIT:

What I am using .. via Joel's response:

```
regExPattern = @"(?<tag>\bProcess Xml Sent to XCEProducer.cProducer\b)(?<xmlFragment>\s+(.*)$)";
```

Comment: I can't get the "line =" code to show up, any help?

Comment: `true==true` would always be true..you don't need that

Comment: Yeah, I know about the true==true, it was a temp work around to get into the block code.

Comment: Who downvoted my question?  Geeze.  I explained my problem and gave my attempt code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If XML is the only thing lefton that line after that tag , just do

```
regExPattern = @"(?<tag>\bXml Sent to Engine\b)\s+(.*)$"
```

Comment: Yes, xml is the only thing left.  Let me check this and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Ok...you got me over the hump.  Thanks.  I marked as "the answer".